# String array sorting automatically while initialization

Tags: arrays, string, sorting

I have a string array and I am just initializing it as below in a java file (Constants.java)

```java
public static final String[] MY_ARRAY = {"xyz","pqr","trw","abc"};
```

I am using this `MY_ARRAY` in another java file in  main method as below:

```java
String [] HEADER = Constants.MY_ARRAY;
// MY_ARRAY is coming as sorted in natural order ("abc","pqr","trw","xyz").
```

This is an intermittent issue and not happening every time I run my program. I also have another final static String arrays like MY_ARRAY and have different strings. I am facing same issue with all these string arrays. I cant say when exactly this will happen but it happens intermittently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: I am using java 8 and I have many work around to stop MY_ARRAY to be sorted but I just wanted to know why string are being sort intermittently at the time of String array Initialization.

Comment: Are you sorting `HEADER` at some point?